# extreme burner installtion problems

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, hardware, programming

I'm newbie in ubuntu and I'm trying to program an AVR micro-controller , i searched a lot for a suitable program and found at last a program called "extreme burner" but it doesn't work !

```
apt-get install avrprog
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package avrprog is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'avrprog' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: `avrprog` is dropped from Ubuntu repositories. It does not install to 16.04.

Comment: so what do u recommended for avr programing ?

Answer (score 0):

You must download file, first.
This is download link eXtreme Burner for Ubuntu (Latest v.10.10):
http://www.extremeelectronics.co.in/software/BurnerAVR/xAVR_Ubuntu.tar.gz

second step, extract file.

enter folder xAVR :
$ cd xAVR

and you can run the program :
$ ./avrprog